# What is __multicall__ argument and why it is deprecated?

Tags: python, pytest

I use pytest as a part of my application. I create some fixtures to use inside tests and then run pytest.main with some tests.

Plugin:

```
class MyPlugin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...some code here

    @pytest.fixture
    def fixture1(self, request):
        return self.something
```

Call to pytest:

```
plugin = MyPlugin()
pytest.main(cmdline, plugins=[plugin])
```

I'm getting warning on each app run with pytest:

`WI1 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest_timeout.py:68 'pytest_runtest_protocol' hook uses deprecated __multicall__ argument`

What is that, why it is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pytest_timeout plugin you use triggers it
it should get updated

Comment: Yes, it is. I think this is distro issue (both python-pytest and python-pytest-timeout comes from distro). Thank you!